# Ftp file transfer using Spring framework

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

I'm trying to upload file with Spring, but I'm facing problem which I don't understand.

Here is my definition of an adapter and the session factory:

```
<bean id="ftpClientFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <property name="port" value="21"/>
    <property name="username" value="test"/>
    <property name="password" value="test"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="0"/>
</bean>

<si:channel id="ftpChannel"/>

<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound"
                                  channel="ftpChannel"
                                  remote-directory="/Users/testUser"
                                  session-factory="ftpClientFactory"/>
```

and here's error I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ftpOutbound': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler#0' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.SessionFactoryFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [boolean]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [boolean]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value []
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should add `cache-sessions="true"` to the 
`<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>` configuration.

But from other side Spring Integration 2.1 is very old version and it is already is EOL. Would be better if you switch to the latest version: http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration

Comment: I have added cache-sessions and switched to latest version of spring integration, and now I'm getting this error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 553 in XML document from class path resource [citrus-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp/spring-integration-ftp.xsd; lineNumber: 553; columnNumber: 71; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'integration:smartLifeCycleAttributeGroup' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.

Comment: You should upgrade all Spring Integration jars and configure your IDE for Spring Nature to resolve XSD from CLASSPATH not the Internet. And `cache-sessions` has been removed since 2.2. With newest versions you should just configure `CachingSessionFactory` around the target `sesssionFactory` to achieve caching ability.